# Why are alerts using a language other than English to display the alert's title?

Tags: alert, localization

I have a SharePoint 2010 portal, and it seems as though some people receive alerts with a language other than English for the alert's title.

> You have successfully created an alert for '럢镛乪佟犋֣␓'

Can someone help me understand how that would happen? Is that a configuration on the SharePoint side? Configuration on each site? Configuration in Outlook?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/6c7e713d-70e8-49f5-8ff5-7337b56e2bfe?prof=required&lc=1033

My suggestion is to install the SMTP4DEV tool mentioned in the thread (or something similar) to intercept the emails from SharePoint. This will help you in debugging. If the emails are still in an alternative language in this tool, then there is a SharePoint setting crossed up.  If they are fine in this tool, then Exchange or Outlook are likely the culprit.  Unless you have installed additional language packs for SharePoint, I doubt SharePoint is the cause.